# jSignature Dynamic width & Height for responsive web page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have initiated a jSignature canvas inside a bootstrap modal to show up once the modal has been opened. My question is how can i dynamically set the signature pad to be 100% width and height of the modal body div. It automatically sets the width to 100% but the height varies due to the different aspects of browser window sizes.

Thank you

Comment: I am also looking for a way to make jSignature automatically size itself to fit the container.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this issue myself. I ended up setting the width of the canvas with jQuery after initialising jSignature. I did, however, have to have a fixed height on the jSignature.

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="signatureID"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#signatureID").jSignature({ height: 400 });
$("#signatureID").find(".jSignature").css("width", "100%")
```